# Add wifi network name in notification?

Tags: wi-fi, notification-bar

I saw on one ROM (based on Cyanogen 10) it had wifi network name by the carrier name, and i want to make it work on stock CM.

Comment: So you want to display your WiFi SSID (WiFi name) besides your mobile operator name? And there is no such thing as *stock CM*. It's either [CyanogenMod](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cyanogenmod/info) or [Stock Rom](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/stock-rom/info)

Comment: Why would you not just flash Cyanogen? I'm sure it has a ton of other features that you will enjoy as well and as far as I know, you can't make your device display the SSID on the notification bar (I don't even think people can write an app that does this without root access anyway).

Comment: @Sid Yes, i want to display WiFi SSID beside my operator name. And soory for Stock CM I ment not modifyed. I know that i need to modify some thing in SystemUI but i don't know what. Can you tell me?

Comment: @John I'm on Cyanogen mod, and there is alredy display the SSID on the notification bar in SleamBeam Rom. And i have root on my phone.