# Show current SSID under WiFi indicator in Notification panel

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, quick-settings

I tried searching for a solution but this seems so stupidly trivial I can't even find any posts about it, not even a hint in those Android tips 'n tricks articles. The closest I could find is [Add wifi network name in notification?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48507/add-wifi-network-name-in-notification), but it wasn't really applicable to my issue here.

I'd like to show my current WiFi SSID below the WiFi indicator in the Notification panel. See image below for example, I've marked where it should be with a red border.

Reason for asking is because a friend of mine with the exact same phone shows the SSID below the WiFi indicator, I saw it with my very own eyes. His phone was *not* rooted, just to be clear.

**Phone details:**

- Model: Samsung SM-G900F
- Android version: 6.0.1
- Kernel: 3.4.0
- Home screen: Google Now Launcher.
- Rooted: no

I just tried changing Home screen to Samsung's TouchWiz, but it made no difference for the SSID indicator.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, or please let me know if I didn't provide enough information. The fact it's such a small issue is bothering me even more.

[image: Show SSID in Notification panel]

Comment: Use an app like [SSID Notify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.playmoremusic.android.wifiname) ?

Comment: I'd like to use the Android native function for this when I know it exists somehow. Besides, I can't tell what *SSID Notify* actually tries to do. The description and screenshots made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think android version is not the same anymore as on the question but on 7.0 (Nougat) if you pull down the status bar using 1 finger you don't see the wifi SSID (1st picture) and if you use 2 fingers you can see more icons and details (2nd picture), including the SSID. See pictures (on the same fone). (obs: pulling with 1 finger and pulling a 2nd time is the same as pulling with 2 fingers)

[image: Using 1 single finger]
[image: Using 2 fingers]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be that you have disabled SSID broadcasting in your router settings. I think this may depend on the type of router you are using too. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue unfortunately. The WLAN is broadcasting SSID. I frequently use 4 different WLANs as well so I doubt it has anything to do with the WLAN settings

Comment: Perhaps your phone needs upgrading, that might fix the issue.